# How to add JBoss Server in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, server

I am new to JBoss and have just installed Eclipse. I have added a project to the workspace and now I want to deploy it to a Jboss server. However, in the *New Server Runtime Environment* list, JBoss is not available:

[image: New Server Runtime Environment without JBoss]

I am using the below Eclipse version:

> Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)

Why is JBoss not listed as a runtime environment? What do I have to do to add JBoss to the list of available runtime environments?

Comment: Clear document is [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/eclipse/jboss-eclipse/jboss-and-eclipse).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the solution follow below steps

1. In Eclipse Mars go to Help-> Install New Software
2. Click on add button and paste the URL of the update site which is in our case: [Eclipse Mars tools for Jboss](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/mars/)
3. Now select the **JBossAS** Tools plugin and Click "Next"

Answer (score 29):

Since Eclipse Mars 2 (JEE edition), JBoss Tools can be directly dowloaded from the *New Server* interface:

[image: New Server]

Selecting *JBoss AS, WildFly, & EAP Server Tools* will install JBoss Tools. After installation, the view will include JBoss/WildFly:

[image: New Server with JBoss/WildFly]

---

*Follow the below instructions if Eclipse Mars 1 is used.*

It is simply not built-in into the Eclipse distribution. You need to install [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/) from the Eclipse marketplace (*Help* -> *Eclipse Marketplace* and search for "JBoss Tools").

More specifically, the feature you are asking for is documented here:

http://tools.jboss.org/features/server.html

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, what I did was change the eclipse.ini point JDK version 1.8. Jboss Tools required 1.8.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

Answer (score 2):

If server or tool you wanted(like glassfish,jboss) isn't listed then click `download Additional server adapters` and download desired adapter.After that all related servers and tools will be listed then follow instruction here -

[Jboss Community](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.0.Final/en/as/html/runtimes_servers.html)

http://riccardotramma.com/2013/06/install-jboss-and-use-it-in-eclipse-juno/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. It required two passes through `Window/Preferences`...

```
Window/Preferences/Server/Runtime Environments
```

Add...
   Select Red Hat JBoss Middleware
   Next
      Accept the license agreement

Installation takes a few minutes and requires an Eclipse restart

After the restart:

```
 Window/Preferences/Server/Runtime Environments
```

Add...
   Select JBoss Community/JBoss xxx Runtime
   Next
      Set the home directory and click the "**Download and install**" link

Select the version to download

Accept the license agreement

Comment: Actually you are correct. It needs two passes through `Window/Preference`. And reasonably good instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to the response of @Magnilex, (and for now...) you must run Eclipse Mars with a JDK 8 or the server adapters of JBoss Community don't appear (see the first chapter of http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-06-23-beta1-for-mars.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the possible solutions that I came across, but none of them worked for me to install the jboss server in the eclipse IDE. Everytime I ended with one error(i.e Unable to load the repository), then I came to cross with below solution

Here is the solution follow below steps

1. In Eclipse  go to ***Help-> Eclipse MarketPlace***
2. Search for ***Red Hat CodeReady Studio(Developer Studio)***  and install it after accepting the agreement and install it.
3. ***Restart the eclipse*** inorder to reflect the changes in the eclipse
4. Goto servers and look for the jboss run time enivironment which will be there and load the server to the eclipse

If you have any doubt regarding installation in eclipse IDE,go through the below link

http://riccardotramma.com/2013/06/install-jboss-and-use-it-in-eclipse-juno/