# Eclipse Mars not showing Jboss Server

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars

Here is the things I tried

1. In Eclipse Mars go to Help-> Install New Software
2. Click on add button and paste the URL of the update site which is in our case: [Eclipse Mars tools for Jboss](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/mars/)
3. Now select the **JBossAS** Tools plugin and Click "Next"

**EDIT :-**

Even after doing above points i am not able to see the Jboss server in eclipse mars so i tried below

Go to eclipse market place - > search for Jboss -> Then from List Red Hat Jboss Developer Studio(Mars) 9.0->Confirm

Even now i am not able to see Jboss server in the eclipse add server list so not able to run my application in Jboss server .

Can any one tell me what can be the issue why Jboss server not listed in the server List?

[image]

**EDIT 1 :-**

[image]

Comment: Why don't you go with my proposition here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245959/how-to-add-jboss-server-in-eclipse. Install JBoss Tools from the Eclipse marketplace.

Comment: That i already done but still not appearing..check added image for reference in question

Comment: Sorry i did not found any instruction inside eclipse before installing it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need Java 8 to run Eclipse with JBoss Tools 4.3.0.Beta1 even if you don't build and deploy with this version of Java (ie, you can still build and deploy on Java 6 or 7).
See http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-06-23-beta1-for-mars.html#java-8-to-run-eclipse-older-runtimes-ok-for-builds-deployment

Comment: For above this using Java8 for eclipse we have to change in JAVA-HOME ? Then let us suppose i am running maven command through command prompt it will also run with java8 and class compile with java8 it will not create a issue ?

Comment: I tried running eclipse with jdk8 but jboss servers are still not visible in the list. Any guesses ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running with Java 8 ? JBoss Tools/Developer Studio Beta on Mars requires Java 8.

You can use it to develop against older versions of Java just fine though.

Comment: No i am  running with Java7

Comment: try with java 8 and see if it makes a difference.

You should already have gotten a dialog saying Java 8 was needed though if you installed it.

Comment: That dialogue i did not get but u r right its Java8 issue

Comment: JBoss Tools installed. Did not get any dialog. Changed to java8 though and no difference: JBoss does not appear in New Server Window nor in Add "Runtime Environments".

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,I solved it by doing the following

You can install runtimes into Eclipse by selecting Window → Preferences menu and then selecting Server → Runtime Environments from the categories available on the left.

After that jboss appear in the server view

Comment: If Eclipse does not show JBoss in "Add Server" window, it will not show JBoss in Runtime Environments either.

Answer (score 0):

This is b/c eclipse mars installation process goes through installer which will pick the JRE which is installed that time(in my case that was 1.7) and the JBoss need java 1.8 for proper installation b/c of that every time when u start eclipse it shows that some files are not install for jBoss…After eclipse installation if you change the JRE environment it will not change for JBOSS installion….
 For me ; i removed JDk1.7 from Application/Java/VirtualMachineEmviroment(JDK1.8 should remain intact) and Re-run eclipse installer. Now install again Jboss tools form eclipse market…This time for new server configuration , there will be Jboss Community folder...

Comment: Not necessarily, most Eclipse "installers" are just ZIP files:

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/mars/2